# Getting SQL group query from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm developing a simple quiz game and I have difficulties in creating an SQL (SQL Server 2016) query. I have the following related tables:

> [Authors]
>  ID
> Name
>
> [Quizzes]
>  ID
> AuthorID *(points to ID in [Authors])*
>
> [QuizGames]
>  ID
> QuizID *(points to ID in [Quizzes])*
>
> [GamesPlayed]
>  ID
> QuizGameID *(points to ID in [QuizGames])*
>
> [Players]
>  ID
> GamePlayedID *(points to ID in [GamesPlayed])*
> DatePlayed

Given an author's ID (in the first table) I need to get the total number of Players (last table) for all his games played in the last 6 months. For example, I'd need a Stored Procedure /Query that returns me:

```
Feb2020  Jan2020   Dec2019   Nov2019   Oct 2019   Sep2019
1404      2512      6521      1421      2150       1120
```

Basically I would need to get author's ID from first table, then look for all the quizzes he createdin the second table, then look for all the games (in the 3rd table) created with his quizzes, then look for all the games (in the 4th table) played with his games, and then look for the players (in the last table, grouped by last 6 months) that played his games.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried? Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

Comment: You "need a stored procedure", so you start by writing one. This is a not a free code-writing service. This approach is generally known as a pivot - start by searching that term. If you are new to tsql, this might be beyond your abilities at this point. In addition, this type of goal can often be accomplished far more easily in a reporting tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.DatePlayed, COUNT(p.Id)
FROM [Player] p
JOIN [GamesPlayed] gp on gp.Id = p.GamePlayedId
JOIN [QuizGames] qg on qg.Id = gp.QuizGameId
JOIN [Quizzes] q on q.Id = qg.QuizId
JOIN [Author] a on a.Id = q.AuthorId
WHERE p.DatePlayed >= DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0,DATEADD(M, -6, GETUTCDATE())), 0)
GROUP BY p.DatePlayed
```

Comment: It seems to work but it's grouped by p.DatePlayed (which is a date/time field). I made a small change:
`SELECT MONTH(p.DatePlayed)
...
GROUP BY MONTH(p.DatePlayed)`
and it seems to work.